# Are modern black & white movies shot in colour?

Tags: production, film-techniques, black-and-white

A few movies are still released in black & white, largely for artistic reasons.

Are such movies shot in colour, and then converted to black & white for release? Or are they usually filmed in black & white? Is one approach more common than the other?

Comment: Technically, every movie ever has been shot in color :P

Comment: Technically, Calvin's dad [answered this](https://calvin-and-hobbes-comic-strips.blogspot.dk/2011/11/calvin-asks-dad-about-old-black-and.html) a long time ago. Not necessarily altogether accurately, but answered nonetheless!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_black-and-white_films_produced_since_1970) suggests that they are filmed in color and the converted to monochrome on post-production

> Since the 1970s, fiction feature films have been filmed almost exclusively in color. Some films after the transition to color are occasionally presented in black-and-white for budgetary or stylistic reasons. This is a list of notable feature films whose majority of running time is in black-and-white or monochrome/sepia tone and made after the 1960s. Many modern black-and-white films are shot in color and converted in post-production.

Obviously, there are exceptions (at the link) but, it seems pretty logical to at least have **the option** of switching back to color should there be a desire to do so.

I covered the reasoning (partly) in a [**question about *this issue***](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67771/why-did-filmmakers-need-permission-to-film-in-black-and-white) which is included in the list at the link.

Comment: You say _Young Frankenstein_ but the question you linked to is regarding _The Elephant Man_

Comment: *The Artist* (2011) was also shot in color. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Artist_(film)#Production): *Though presented in black-and-white, it was shot in color by cinematographer Guillaume Schiffman ([src](http://entertainment.time.com/2012/01/19/what-is-this-artist-movie-thats-winning-all-the-awards/)).* Perhaps you could add a bit about that to your answer, given that it's one of the most recent black and white films?

Comment: Clerks was shot in monochrome because that is all they could afford.

Comment: It's less about the option of switching to color than it is about being able to control exactly how the colors are mapped to black and white.

Comment: For digital cinema, does anyone make image-sensors without the Bayer Filter? That way you'd get very crisp and detailed B+W image data with even better dark/night performance.

Comment: @Dai Yes: https://nofilmschool.com/2012/11/red-epic-monochrome-vs-red-epic-comparison

Comment: It seems that (from relatively recent movies) Jim Jarmusch's Coffee and Cigarettes (2003) was shot on a black and white negative camera stock. See https://books.google.com/books?id=fg7TCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq="Coffee+and+Cigarettes"+camera+stock&source=bl&ots=xRoR6Usx7p&sig=ZcsARQLxRR8EelMX-R1nXsmXUlA&hl=cs&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q="Coffee and Cigarettes" camera stock

Comment: If you shoot in color, you also have the option to grade different colors brighter or darker to improve contrast between some colors in post.

Comment: I do believe that _Schindler's List_ was shot in black and white, though the girl's red coat was added in post production.